# rails error with geocoder, geocomplete and double nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am using geocoder and geocomplete.
I have haml code in registration/new view

```
   = f.fields_for :profile do |p|
    = p.fields_for :location, Location.new do |build|
     = build.text_field :address ,:id => 'geo-input-address'
```

Its generating html:

```
<input id="geo-input-address" name="user[profile_attributes][location_attributes][address]" type="text" data-validate="true">
```

In my application.haml

```
  %script{"type"=>"text/javascript","src"=>"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"}
```

in application.js

```
$("#geo-input-address").geocomplete();
```

but it is giving error in console
when i m running
 $("#geo-input-address").geocomplete(); in console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined$.extend.initGeocoder @ jquery.geocomplete.js?body=1:169$.extend.init @ jquery.geocomplete.js?body=1:99GeoComplete @ jquery.geocomplete.js?body=1:91(anonymous function) @ jquery.geocomplete.js?body=1:545jQuery.extend.each @ jquery.js?body=1:384jQuery.fn.jQuery.each @ jquery.js?body=1:137$.fn.geocomplete @ jquery.geocomplete.js?body=1:541(anonymous function) @ VM1842:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM1841:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM1841:816InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM1841:682
```

First of all i am using nested forms..
I am using complex nested form.
I have 3 models

Location

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :profiles
  geocoded_by :address
end
```

Profile

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

User (Devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

Any idea, please help

Comment: This could help you https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/390

Comment: Yep when you get `google is not defined` in your browser console window, it means that the google object is not defined. It is defined by loading the javascript file from google. So it probably means the javascript was not loaded, _in the browser_, or you had another javascript error first.